# pyparsing : group text between dates

Tags: pyparsing

I have log files that contain a a date/time with a varied # of lines between the next date/time

ex.

time-date
2/07/18 13:55:00.983

```
msecVal = pyparsing.Word(pyparsing.nums, max=3)
numPair = pyparsing.Word(pyparsing.nums, exact=2)
dateStr = pyparsing.Combine(numPair + '/' + numPair + '/' + numPair)

timeString = pyparsing.Combine(numPair + ':' + numPair + ':' +     numPair\               
       + '.' + msecVal)
```

log file will be

```
time:date:  line of text
    possible 2nd line of text
    possible 3rd line of text...
    time:date:  line of text
time:date: line of text
    possible 2nd line of text
    possible 3rd line of text...
    possible <n> line of text...
time:date:  line of text
```

Input will be a large text log file in the above format. I'd like to produce a list list of grouped elements

```
[[time],[all text until next time]],[[time],[all text until next time]...
```

I can do this if each time/date entry were a single line.. it's spanning between a random # of multiple lines until the next time/date entry I'm having problems with.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I interpret your definition of a log enty:

"A date-time at the beginning of a line, followed by a colon, followed by everything
up until the next date-time at the beginning of a line, even if there might be date-times
embedded in the line."

There are two pyparsing features that you need to solve this:

- LineStart - to distinguish date-times at the start of the line vs those in the body of the line
- SkipTo - quick way to skip over unstructured text until a matching expression is found

I added these expressions to your code (I imported pyparsing as 'pp' because I am a lazy typist):

```
dateTime = dateStr + timeString

# log entry date-time keys only match if they are at the start of the line
dateTimeKey = pp.LineStart() + dateTime

# define a log entry as a date-time key, followed by everything up to the next 
# date-time key, or to the end of the input string
# (use results names to make it easy to get at the parts of the log entry)
logEntry = pp.Group(dateTimeKey("time") + ':' + pp.Empty()
                    + pp.SkipTo(dateTimeKey | pp.StringEnd())("body"))
```

I converted your sample to have different date times in it for testing, and we get this:

```
sample = """\
2/07/18 13:55:00.983:  line of text
    possible 2nd line of text
    possible 3rd line of text...
    2/07/19 13:55:00.983:  line of text
2/07/20 13:55:00.983: line of text
    possible 2nd line of text
    possible 3rd line of text...
    possible <n> line of text...
2/07/21 13:55:00.983:  line of text
"""

print(pp.OneOrMore(logEntry).parseString(sample).dump())
```

Gives:

```
[['2/07/18', '13:55:00.983', ':', 'line of text\n    possible 2nd line of text\n    possible 3rd line of text...\n    2/07/19 13:55:00.983:  line of text'], ['2/07/20', '13:55:00.983', ':', 'line of text\n    possible 2nd line of text\n    possible 3rd line of text...\n    possible <n> line of text...'], ['2/07/21', '13:55:00.983', ':', 'line of text']]
[0]:
  ['2/07/18', '13:55:00.983', ':', 'line of text\n    possible 2nd line of text\n    possible 3rd line of text...\n    2/07/19 13:55:00.983:  line of text']
  - body: 'line of text\n    possible 2nd line of text\n    possible 3rd line of text...\n    2/07/19 13:55:00.983:  line of text'
  - time: ['2/07/18', '13:55:00.983']
[1]:
  ['2/07/20', '13:55:00.983', ':', 'line of text\n    possible 2nd line of text\n    possible 3rd line of text...\n    possible <n> line of text...']
  - body: 'line of text\n    possible 2nd line of text\n    possible 3rd line of text...\n    possible <n> line of text...'
  - time: ['2/07/20', '13:55:00.983']
[2]:
  ['2/07/21', '13:55:00.983', ':', 'line of text']
  - body: 'line of text'
  - time: ['2/07/21', '13:55:00.983']
```

I also had to convert your `num_pair` to:

```
numPair = pp.Word(pp.nums, max=2)
```

else it would not match the leading single-digit '2' in your sample date.